# filtering select drop down menu to filter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning react and have a simple app using a countries api. 
My app successfully displays all the countries and allows user to filter countries in a search input.

I want to be able to use a select dropdown to show countries by region example: Europe, Asia, Africa etc.

Heres my code:

```js
const Homepage = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [searchedCountry, setSearchedCountry] = useState('');
  const [region, setRegion] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect');
    axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearchedCountry(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleSelect = (event) => {
    setRegion(event.target.value);
  };

  // Filter function
  const filteredCountries = countries.filter((country) =>
    country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedCountry.toLowerCase())
  );
  const filteredRegion = countries.filter((country) =>
    country.region.toLowerCase().includes(region.toLocaleLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <div className='homepage'>
      <input type='text' onChange={handleSearch} />
      <select value={region} onChange={handleSelect}>
        <option value='All'>All</option>
        <option value='Europe'>Europe</option>
        <option value='Asia'>Asia</option>
        <option value='Africa'>Africa</option>
        <option value='Americas'>Americas</option>
        <option value='Oceania'>Oceania</option>
      </select>
      <CountryList
        filteredCountries={filteredCountries}
        filteredRegion={filteredRegion}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And my country list

```js
const CountryList = ({ filteredCountries, filteredRegion }) => {
  return (
    <div className='card-list'>
      {filteredCountries.map((country) => (
        <Country key={country.name} id={country.name} country={country} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Currently the filterRegion function is passed to the list component but I'm unsure how to make it so when region is selected only countries of that region are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filtering countries based 'name' and 'region' separately, You can combine as one filter function like below and you dont need the 2nd argument to `ContryList`. Hope this helps.

```
const filteredCountries = countries.filter(
  country =>
    country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedCountry.toLowerCase()) &&
    country.region.toLowerCase().includes(region.toLocaleLowerCase())
);
```

Comment: Its a good solution, also change ` <option value='All'>All</option>` to ` <option value=''>All</option>`. this should do the job